# replacing a runtime instance of ipset

Tags: iptables, ipset

I have a running instance of iptables and ipset services. Among them one set has a spec similar to this that has 20+ references to it:

```
create_set foo ipmap --network 123.45.67.0/24
add_to_set foo host1
add_to_set foo host2
```

where host1 and 2 are say 123.45.67.5 and 123.45.67.6.

I need to add `host3` to the set that is on a different subnet than 67, e.g., 123.45.66.0. I would like to enlarge the set `foo` to `123.45.0.0/16`. The problem I am getting when trying to re-define `foo` (no error) and add `host3` (say 123.45.66.5) while it is running and then getting the "out of range" error from the `ipset` command. It turns out `ipset` does not reload sets with references.

Now all this is scripted with scripts and makefiles to keep the ipset and iptables services down as little as possible while updating either sets or the rules. There are hundreds of sets and rules saved and reloaded. **Can I (and if yes, how) replace a running set by its enlarged version?** It seems I can only do it by shutting down iptables and ipset, making my changes, and then reloading, but can't rebuild it on the fly; otherwise it complains the set specification is wrong when trying to add the `host3` entry from another subnet. (There may be other hosts all over the place in 123.45.x.x added later on.)

This happens on EL5 and EL6 running either ipset 4.5 or 6.11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create NEW set with

```
ipset create foo-new ...
```

add entries there and then swap the two:

```
ipset swap foo-new foo
```

and destroy the no longer needed set:

```
ipset destroy foo-new
```

Comment: So this is like a shortcut for what I did it seems with my rename.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found something what I believe is acceptable in the end. Should better answers pop up, I will re-evaluate this one.

The trick is to rename the problematic set, and then re-create a new, enlarged, set with the original name, e.g., assuming the sets and IPs in the question:

```
/usr/bin/ipset --rename foo foo-old
/usr/bin/ipset --create foo ipmap 123.45.0.0/16
/usr/bin/ipset --add foo 123.45.67.5
/usr/bin/ipset --add foo 123.45.67.6
/usr/bin/ipset --add foo 123.45.66.5
```

and it worked for me. Can then `--save`. When restarting `ipset`, the references migrated to the new instance and the old can can be safely discarded if not saved.

Comment: This will fail if the set is in use (eg: by an iptables rule).

Comment: It worked for me (precisely in the scenario when `foo` that became `foo-old` was in use).